# "Symbol's function definition is void: cl-macroexpand-all" when trying to install php-mode

Tags: package, cl-lib, php-mode

I'm trying to install [php-mode](https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode), but I keep encountering this error when I run `M-x php-mode`:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: cl-macroexpand-all
```

The error persists whether I install php-mode via MELPA or manually.

Environment: Emacs 24.3.94.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
 of 2014-10-04 on builder10-9.porkrind.org

Why won't php-mode run? Note: I'm relatively new to Emacs, and inexperienced.

Comment: Same problem and same solution for [`cuda-mode`](http://melpa.org/#/cuda-mode) in MELPA (version `cuda-mode-20140704.1357`). When trying to enable `cuda-mode` using `M-x cuda-mode` the error comes, but after using `M-x load-library <RET> cl` the command `M-x cuda-mode` runs without problems.

Comment: `cuda-mode` is [on GitHub](https://github.com/chachi/cuda-mode); consider opening an issue using [its issue tracker](https://github.com/chachi/cuda-mode/issues).

Comment: Here is the [issue](https://github.com/chachi/cuda-mode/issues/1), thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `cl-macroexpand-all` has been obsoleted in Emacs 24.3; you are now supposed to use `macroexpand-all` instead, which is part of core Emacs, not the CL library.

The CL library defines `cl-macroexpand-all` as an alias for `macroexpand-all`, so in principle you could do

```
(require 'cl)
```

in your init file to fix the problem.  However, the `cl` library itself is being deprecated, and using it is not recommended.

I think you should contact the authors of `php-mode` and tell them to use `macroexpand-all`.

Comment: The dev seems to be aware of the issue: [ejmr/php-mode#202](https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode/issues/202)

Answer (score 4):

It's [bug #18845](http://debbugs.gnu.org/db/18/18845.html) in Emacs-24.4.  To work around it, you need to add `(require 'cl)` somewhere before you load php-mode.